# creating jtextfield in existing panel that was created using netbeans

Tags: java, swing

Trying to create a textfield on to a panel that exists and was created using netbeans design. Here is the code:

```
JTextField test1TextField = new JTextField(actTerm.getDescription().length());
test1TextField.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("TestField1"));      

term1TextField.setText(actTerm.getDescription());
openPanel.add(test1TextField);
openPanel.validate();
openPanel.repaint();
openPanel.updateUI();
```

openPanel, as I said was created via netbeans design tool. The validate, repaint, and updateUI, I was just trying different things and all failed. The created textfield does not show up on the panel when run. Don't know what else to try.

Adding following references to openPanel. This is netbeans code not mine:

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout openPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(openPanel);
        openPanel.setLayout(openPanelLayout);
        openPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            openPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(openPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addGroup(openPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(openPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(saveOpenTermsButton)
                        .addGap(70, 70, 70)
                        .addComponent(deleteOpenTermsButton)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(openPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(openPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(term1TextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 267, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 55, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(term2TextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(97, 97, 97))))
        );
        openPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            openPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(openPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addGroup(openPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(term1TextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(term2TextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 143, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(openPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(saveOpenTermsButton)
                    .addComponent(deleteOpenTermsButton))
                .addGap(29, 29, 29))
        );

        rulesTabbedPanel.addTab("Open Rules", openPanel);
```

Comment: How about [`openPanel.revalidate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate()) ?

Comment: @nullpointer: yep, I should have mentioned that, as that is better than `validate()`. Also `updateUI()` should almost never be called unless changing the GUI's look and feel on the fly. Also best to post a valid [mcve] for questions like these.

Comment: OK, so you **are** using GroupLayout -- so choose a different one and see how it goes. Please look at the edits to my answer below, and comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Went to design tool of netbeans and trying different layouts. GridBag did a little better in that I can see a tiny box now but still not there yet. Will keep trying others.

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential issues here, but one major problem is likely due to the layout manager used by openPanel as some managers are easier to work with when adding new components on the fly than others, such as FlowLayout and GridLayout -- very easy to add to, vs. GroupLayout and null layout -- veritable bears.

Find out which layout is used on openPanel, change the layout if necessary, and try again.

Another potential issue is the size of openPanel -- is it even large enough to be seen and to accept a JTextField? Put a border around it and see for yourself.

---

Edit: as pointed out by nullpointer, you should call `revalidate()` on the JPanel after changing components on it, not `validate()` and never `updateUI()` unless you're calling it after changing the GUI's look and feel. If still stuck and the above suggestions don't solve your problem, then create and post a valid [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please check out the link).

---

Edit: OK, your posted code shows that you've given your openPanel a GroupLayout layout manager, and as I mention above, this manager is not very forgiving for when you want to add new components to a container on the fly. You state that the code has been generated by NetBeans, and you're correct, but the layout was selected by you, and you can (and should) select a different one. Look the layouts available in the properties panels for your openPanel container and select a more user-friendly layout. Which one? It really depends on what type of GUI you're trying to create. If you're only adding one component to this JPanel, then the simplest to use is FlowLayout, and you can try that one. Also understand that you can nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager to create pleasing and complex GUI's that look good on all OS's.

You can find the layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).

Comment: bounded by the voting limits +1 from me anyway to the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are few things can go wrong, one them field size and panel layout. Did you change the default layout of openPanel (assuming this is JPanel, FlowLayout is the default of JPanel)?
You can try hard coding value for text field and remove border just for testing

Comment: FlowLayout is the default in netbeans. I'm trying different layouts without much success. I did try hard coding values for text field and removing border among other things...

Comment: @wsteve: correction: FlowLayout is the default layout for JPanels in Swing. If you've experimented and are still stuck, then please show the updated code in your question. Also, please consider reading fully and replying to **all** answers given, not just this one.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've spent too much time trying to make this work. I think I will either 1)create the all jtextFields with netbeans design then just fill them in later when my code runs. Or 2) create the dialog/panel etc myself then create the jtextfields. I know this would work though it's been a while since i've done it. I was just trying to avoid all that work but it may make sense at this point. I could post the entire file on stackoverflow and see if anyone else can figure it out.